# Null Pointer Exception using URLDecoder.decode(string s, string ) in GCMIntentService

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-messaging, urldecode

I use this code (GCMIntentService.java) for decode a message received from the GCM:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message"); // works fine.
try {
     message = URLDecoder.decode(message, "UTF-8"); // decode fine, but get the error below.
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
throw new AssertionError("UTF-8 is unknown");
}
```

The message received is identical to the message sent (encoded). For encode, i use this:

```
String message = URLEncoder.encode(items[0].getMessage(),"UTF-8"); // works fine
```

And i get this error, i can't find cause of null pointer exception.

```
07-19 17:33:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(21742): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-0002223333444-2]
07-19 17:33:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(21742): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 17:33:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(21742):    at com.chat.ak.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:70)
07-19 17:33:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(21742):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
07-19 17:33:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(21742):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
07-19 17:33:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(21742):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 17:33:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(21742):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-19 17:33:44.687: E/AndroidRuntime(21742):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Which line is line 70?

Comment: line 70 is this:  message = URLDecoder.decode(message.trim(), "UTF-8");

Comment: @user2600052 Your line 70 isn't part of your code snippets (or modified). There is a `.trim()`

Comment: Is the third line of my code snippets. I tried with both lines (with and without .trim()), i get the same error.

Comment: @user2600052 Are you sure that `URLDecoder` is the imported class `java.net.URLDecoder` and not something else? If so, you may try to clean and rebuild your whole project

Comment: I forgot to encode the confirmation message. I'm sorry and thank you very much for your help. The above code is correct.